# Drop rows with same value in some columns in dataframe using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I have a dataframe with 5 columns: filename, #line_changed-hist, #line_changed-myers, #line_changed-min, and #line_changed-pat with thousands of data. What I want to do is dropping rows if the last four columns (all line_changed) have same values. Suppose my dataframe called "datamerge3:

```
filename                    #line_changed-hist #line_changed-myers #line_changed-min #line_changed-pat
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.../util/HBaseFsck.java     1808                1806                1806              1806
.../hfile/HFileBlock.java   1036                1032                1032              1040
.../HConnectionManager.java  794                 772                 772               774
.../TestCompatibility.java   762                 762                 762               762
.../master/MockServer.java   605                 605                 605               605
.../TestRowEndpoint.java     598                 598                 598               598
.../TestHBaseFsck.java       576                 572                 572               572
.../TestEndLevel.java         11                   0                   0                 0
```

I need to remove all rows with same values in the last four column (#line_changed). For example data number 4, 5, and 6. Then, save it to new csv file. This is the code I wrote:

```
for nn in range(0,len(datamerge3)-1):
    dmhist = datamerge3.iloc[nn]['#line_changed-hist']
    dmmyers = datamerge3.iloc[nn]['#line_changed-myers']
    dmmin = datamerge3.iloc[nn]['#line_changed-min']
    dmpat = datamerge3.iloc[nn]['#line_changed-pat']
    if ((dmhist == dmmyers) and (dmhist == dmmin) and (dmhist == dmpat)):
        datamerge3.drop([nn])
    else:
        pass

datamerge3.to_csv('diff_file.csv')
```

But the code didn't work. Are there somethings I miss in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the number of unique values in the last four spots and filter on that number being greater than one.

*with `iloc`*

```
df[df.iloc[:, -4:].nunique(1).gt(1)]

                      filename  #line_changed-hist  #line_changed-myers  #line_changed-min  #line_changed-pat
0      .../util/HBaseFsck.java                1808                 1806               1806               1806
1    .../hfile/HFileBlock.java                1036                 1032               1032               1040
2  .../HConnectionManager.java                 794                  772                772                774
6       .../TestHBaseFsck.java                 576                  572                572                572
```

*with `filter`*

```
df[df.filter(regex='^#').nunique(1).gt(1)]

                      filename  #line_changed-hist  #line_changed-myers  #line_changed-min  #line_changed-pat
0      .../util/HBaseFsck.java                1808                 1806               1806               1806
1    .../hfile/HFileBlock.java                1036                 1032               1032               1040
2  .../HConnectionManager.java                 794                  772                772                774
6       .../TestHBaseFsck.java                 576                  572                572                572
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you can use `diff` and `any` with boolean indexing:

```
df[df.iloc[:,-4:].diff(axis=1).fillna(0).any(1)]
```

Output:

```
                      filename  #line_changed-hist  #line_changed-myers  #line_changed-min  #line_changed-pat
1      .../util/HBaseFsck.java              1808.0               1806.0             1806.0             1806.0
2    .../hfile/HFileBlock.java              1036.0               1032.0             1032.0             1040.0
3  .../HConnectionManager.java               794.0                772.0              772.0              774.0
7       .../TestHBaseFsck.java               576.0                572.0              572.0              572.0
```

Comment: Sorry, I added one datum in the dataframe, and the last datum should be there in the output. But it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [query](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) but you need to type the name of columns:

```
df.query("not(line_changed-hist == line_changed-myers and line_changed-hist == line_changed-min and line_changed-hist == line_changed-pat)")
```